# What's the derivative of a function that measures how high the tangent to $1/x$ meets the vertical axis?

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, tangent-line

**Problem**. Let $t(x)$ be the equation of the tangent line to the curve $1/x$ at
the point $(x, 1/x)$.  Let $u(x)$ be the function that maps $x$ to the
intersection that $t(x)$ makes with the $y$-axis.  Compute the
derivative of $u(x)$ at the point $x=1$.

**An interpretation of the problem**.  The problem is asking me to find out how fast the intersection between the $y$-axis and the tangent $t(x)$ is going down as it passes by $x = 1$ as we move $x$ to the right.  I say "going down" because I'm using "fast", which sort of implies that $x$ is time and time moves to the right.

**A solution**.  The derivative of $1/x$ is $- 1/x^{2}$.  It looks like I need to use a general point $x = a$, otherwise I can't get an algebraic formula for $u(x)$. The slope of the tangent at $(a, 1/a)$ will be $-1/a^2$.  Now the tangent line is
\begin{align*}
  t(x) - \frac{1}{a} &= -\frac{1}{a^2}(x - a)\\
                t(x) &= -\frac{x}{a^2} + \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{a} = \frac{-x + 2a}{a^2}.
\end{align*}

It turns out the function $u(x)$ being the function that measures how high $t(x)$ intercepts the vertical axis, we'll end up having $u(a)$ and not $u(x)$ because we'll fix $x$ and let $a$ vary, since the interception happens at $x = 0$.  Therefore,

$$u(a) = t(0) = \frac{2a}{a^2} = \frac{2}{a}.$$

I want the derivative of $u(a)$ at $a = 1$,

\begin{align*}
  u'(a) = \frac{-2}{a^2}.
\end{align*}

At $a=1$, we get $u'(1) = -2$.  The slope of $u(a)$ looks reasonable because it is always negative and because it goes to zero as $a$ grows without a bound.

**Question**.  How do I verify this is correct?

Comment: Looks right to me.